# Excel CONCATENATE with multiple condition is it possible?

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

How to use CONCATENATE with multiple condition?

it is possible?

For example

i have

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID | Name | Date | Status |
| 202 | JJ | 3/4/22 | Absent |
| 202 | JJ | 3/3/22 | Late |
| 201 | JC | 3/1/22 | Early Out |
| 201 | JC | 3/2/22 | Late |

i want to join it by C:C>E1 and C:C <E2 Where B:B =E3

| E | F |
| --- | --- |
| 3/1/22 | ----- |
| 3/4/22 | ---- |
| JJ | 3/4/22 Absent, 3/3/22 Late |
| JC | 3/1/22 Early Out, 3/2/22 Late |

is this possible?

```
Function ConcatenateIf(CriteriaRange As Range, Condition As Variant, ConcatenateRange As Range, Optional Separator As String = ",") As Variant
    Dim xResult As String
    On Error Resume Next
    If CriteriaRange.count <> ConcatenateRange.count Then
    ConcatenateIf = CVErr(xlErrRef)
    Exit Function
    End If
    For i = 1 To CriteriaRange.count
    If CriteriaRange.Cells(i).Value = Condition Then
    If ConcatenateRange.Cells(i).Value <> "" Then
    xResult = xResult & Separator & ConcatenateRange.Cells(i).Value
    End If
    End If
    Next i
    If xResult <> "" Then
    xResult = VBA.Mid(xResult, VBA.Len(Separator) + 1)
    End If
    ConcatenateIf = xResult
    Exit Function
    End Function
```

i already try this but it only join using single condition

is there any posible solution like formula or vba?

Answer (score 1):

If you have ***Microsoft-365*** then can use below formula in <kbd>F4</kbd> cell then drag down.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(TEXT($C$2:$C$5,"M/d/yy") & " " &$D$2:$D$5,($C$2:$C$5>=$E$2)*($C$2:$C$5<=$E$3)*($B$2:$B$5=E4)))
```

[image]

Comment: my excel is only 2016 ther is no textjoin and filter on MS Office 2016